# Get current time on selected video from library using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

[image]

When you pick a video on an iOS device you can look through the video by dragging a playhead at the top of the screen. Is it possible to get this current time later when the image is chosen? Like in my imagePickerController function below where I get the video URL.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
    let info2 = info as NSDictionary

    urlVideo = info2.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL) as! NSURL

}
```

Comment: You mean when the video is chosen, right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The time where the playhead is when you tap choose.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. You’ll have to create your own UI to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using the UIImagePickerController as it doesn't offer support for that. You will have to use a custom controller or create your own.